# Red5 and Android. Stream Audio

Tags: android, audio, streaming, red5, rtmp

I have used an app to stream Android Audio with RTMP, the app is this:
https://github.com/mogo29/Android-RTMP

This app asks for a URL like the following:
rtmp://dir:port/folder

I've created a server with Red5, and used examples to stream flash videos from a folder on my pc, but I don't know how to do for use my app with this server. I'm sure that I can because I've found this video from the creator of the app:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqUUL0QwuMo

Comment: Hi dude. Did you find answer on your question ? Probably could you help me/ I have very similar question related to the same project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865945/streaming-microphone-to-rtmp-red5-and-back-on-android.

Comment: Hi! I didn't found it, in fact, I didn'f finished with that proyect , so I cant help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But do you have an real ip at your home where yo make the streaming, because to do that you should have a fixed ip ex 127.0.0.1 and of course the nessesary ports should be open and after that you can put in your Android app the url rtmp://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:YOUR_PORT/oflaDemo and it should stream.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have "dir", it should be an IP address or host name.

For Red5 and other flash-supporting media servers the port will be:
 * 1935 by default for RTMP and RTMPE
 * 80 for RTMPT
 * 80, 443, 1936 for RTMPS

For the folder portion of the uri, the servers vary. In Red5 the first position is the name of the "application" and any path items after that are "rooms". For FMS and Wowza you'll have to work-in "*definst*".

So putting this altogether, for Red5 it would look like this for a local server using RTMP:

```
rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/yourappname
```