# Streaming microphone to RTMP (red5) and back on android

Tags: android, rtmp, red5

I found this application in github https://github.com/mogo29/Android-RTMP. This app do all what I want. This is demo vide of this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqUUL0QwuMo.

I tried to run this app with oflaDemo (rtmp://172.24.224.34:1935/oflaDemo) but I can't send or recive some voice from my Android.

Could you please help me. How I need configure red5 for working with this app.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. For make this working properly you should also pass stream name to server.